# Is there a reason why one can't have a static and a non-static method with identical signature?

Tags: java, overloading, static-methods

I just realized the following does not compile:

```
class MyCoolClass {
    static void do(){..}
    void do(){..}
}
```

**Is there a good reason why this is not allowed? Maybe it would cause some problem that I'm currently missing?**

The only problem I can see currently is that someone might try to call the static method and actually calls the non-static one. But that sounds comparable with static methods on subclasses that hide each other, so I wouldn't consider that a "good" reason.

If one considers the object a method is called on the 0th argument to that method it even would be quite normal overloading of the method.

In case you are wondering: I would like to have this because it would allow creating a shortcut for `new MyCoolClass().do()` as `MyCoolClass.do()` or with static import even as `do()`.

Comment: If you need a "shortcut" for `new MyCoolClass().do()`, why wouldn't `do()`  be just a static method? Clearly it doesn't seem to depend on the contents of the instance, if that's a common way to call the method.

Comment: @Kayaman Why do you think it does not depend on the contents of the instance? It's just common use case to create a new instance and then call do() on it, but other users get an instance from wherever and need to perform ok(). So I need both versions.

Comment: I don't see it as a common use case. I would find it confusing to have an instance method, but with a sidenote of "if you don't have an instance, we'll just create it for you". Can you give any real life example?

Comment: "Why do you think it does not depend on the contents of the instance?" - It *cannot*. If both do exactly the same in static context or non-static context, then their implementation cannot depend on any non-static state.

Comment: @Fildor nobody said they do the same thing! The opposite is true. The static thing does the same as the non-static PLUS creating an instance. If it helps envision the methods actually returning the this or the freshly created instance.

Comment: @Kayaman `MyCoolClass` is a builder (with an unwieldy name) and `do` are actually multiple methods, making up a fluent interface.

Comment: Ah, oh. I somehow assumed that. My bad. Then maybe this could help: One static method `static void do(MyCoolClass inst)` that calls `void doNonStatic()` if `inst != null` and else first creates the instance? So you can call it with `MyCoolClass.do( someInstance )` or `MyCoolClass.do(null)` ... just an idea.

Comment: @Fildor I really don't like passing `null`, anyway I have plenty possibly solutions for my API design challenge. This question is just about understanding the design decision the java creators made.

Comment: @JensSchauder Yeah, just realized I tried answering a question you did not ask. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the Java compiler uses the name of the method and the ordered list of parameter types to uniquely identify the method within the class.  static is a modifier flag and is not considered part of the unique identification.  Unique identification is also important at runtime because the class file contains only those keys necessary to identify the method.  The class name where the method is, then the method name, then the parameter list.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be problematic to handle when you are creating an object. As you probably know, you can call a static function through object reference like:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
s.do(); //can be static method, can be normal method
```

Of course, it's rare to call static method through object, but it's possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But It is not only rare, it is actively discouraged by triggering a warning and there is no reason why you need to do this. You can always improve your code be calling it on the class directly if you want the static method.

Comment: @JensSchauder isn't this an argument against your "requirement", too?

Comment: @Fildor I don't see why.